# HiveError! The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have one word list. I want to put a word in two different boxes in `listview.builder()`.

(*Favorite Box and Learned Box*)

> "HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes."

I am getting this error.

Is there a way to put a data in two different boxes?

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, I want the user to add a word to the desired list according to his request.

Comment: What are the benefits of storing in two different boxes? You can save it in one box and then use it in two ListViews.

Comment: @SulaymonNe'matov I updated the question content. Can you look again to understand the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. If you need to save the same object in multiple boxes, you need to remove the `extends HiveObject` part in the model class.

Comment: You can add single parameter to this object to define. It is the worst option to save same thing in two different boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from getting the actual error, so let's an example, we want to work with a custom object called `ObjectExample` that extends `HiveObject` like this:

```
 @HiveType(typeId: 0)
  class ObjectExample extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String? exampleText;
}
```

After that, I made an adapter for it, [Generate adapter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter?id=generate-adapter).

Now in our `main()`, if we tried to store it like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ObjectExampleAdapter());
  final box1 = await Hive.openBox("box1");
  final box2 = await Hive.openBox("box2");
  final a = ObjectExample();
  box1.put("key", a);
  box2.put("key", a); 

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

It will throw the error :

```
HiveError (HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes.)
```

We cannot save the same instance in different boxes, so what we need here is to store the same `ObjectExample` for us to work with, but different instances of each `Hive` box we made.

So in order to do it, we can add a `copy` getter  in the `ObjectExample` class that will create a new different instance ( copy ) with the same values of our properties ( in my example I have only the `exampleText` property ) each time the `copy` getter is called:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class ObjectExample extends HiveObject {
  ObjectExample get copy {
    final objectInstance = ObjectExample()..exampleText = exampleText;
    return objectInstance;
  }

  @HiveField(0)
  String? exampleText;
}
```

so now we could call it like this:

```
 void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ObjectExampleAdapter());
  final box1 = await Hive.openBox("box1");
  final box2 = await Hive.openBox("box2");
  final a = ObjectExample()..exampleText = "Hello World";   
  box1.put("key", a.copy); // different copy but with same properties
  box2.put("key", a.copy); // different copy but with same properties

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

**That's it!**

You can now get those objects and use them fine in your project like this:

```
  print(box1.get("key")); // Instance of 'ObjectExample'
  print(box1.get("key").exampleText); // Hello World
  print("-------");
  print(box2.get("key")); // Instance of 'ObjectExample'
  print(box2.get("key").exampleText); // Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another Hive object of your type and populate it with the data that you require (in short: you can make a copy).

That still gives you the benefit of using a Hive object instead of a plain Dart object while achieving what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer to include a _code_ example?